# No visible @interface for 'SKPaymentQueue' declares the selector 'presentCodeRedemptionSheet'

Tags: react-native, in-app-purchase, react-native-ios, react-native-iap

Curious if anyone else getting similar this trying to build via XCode or RN CLI?

Since upgrading to `react-native-iap` *5.2.0.*

Error

> No visible @interface for 'SKPaymentQueue' declares the selector 'presentCodeRedemptionSheet'

Screenshot

[image: XCode 11.5 - No visible @interface for 'SKPaymentQueue' declares the selector 'presentCodeRedemptionSheet']

Codeblock

```objectivec
RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(presentCodeRedemptionSheet:(RCTPromiseResolveBlock)resolve
                  reject:(RCTPromiseRejectBlock)reject) {
    if (@available(iOS 14.0, *)) {
        [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] presentCodeRedemptionSheet];
        resolve(nil);
    } else {
        reject([self standardErrorCode:2], @"This method only available above iOS 14", nil);
    }
}
```

XCode 11.5, no build errors with 50-odd other native libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Downgrade/stick to `react-native-iap` [5.1.3](https://github.com/dooboolab/react-native-iap/issues/1204#issuecomment-741881951) for a successful build for time being, until patch 5.2.1+.

If you're using `react-native-iaphub`, then [6.0.1](https://github.com/iaphub/react-native-iaphub/issues/39)+ too.